# rails sidekiq worker timeout error are coming without completing the execution of worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I am using gem 'sidekiq', '~> 6.0.0' in my rails application. One of my worker are returning timeout error with uncompleted its execution at the staging server but it runs fine on localhost. I know whatever works my worker did that works required more time to execute but it runs fine on localhost but not in staging server. I am unable to figure out it is what the issue. Please help someone me for sorting out the same.

Thank you

Solution on `timeout` error

Comment: Are you dealing with the same data locally and in production?
What is you job doing? Creates records? is there a memory leak?

Comment: Is your staging server at Heroku ? cause it kills everything that goes beyond 30 seconds. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout